# How to find visible bluetooth devices in Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, wireless

I need to find the list of visible Bluetooth devices with their respective details in the range of my Bluetooth modem. I only need to do Bluetooth 2.0 and below. I don't need to do Bluetooth 4.0.

Like you do on an Android phones using "Search for devices".

I'm sorry I can't give any code I tried because I don't know how to do Bluetooth with python.

Comment: What platform are you wanting to do this on? Android? Linux? Something else?

Comment: @CharlieKilian I'd like to be able do it on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[PyBluez](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez):

```
from bluetooth import *

print "performing inquiry..."

nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names = True)

print "found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices)

for name, addr in nearby_devices:
     print " %s - %s" % (addr, name)
```

See also [Programming Bluetooth using Python](http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/2007/01/programming_bluetooth_using_python-shtml/)

The important thing is you can use `lookup_names = True`

from bluez Docs:

```
if lookup_names is False, returns a list of bluetooth addresses.
if lookup_names is True, returns a list of (address, name) tuples
```

Comment: prebuilt for windows:  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez

Comment: PyBluez seems to be deprecated, it is not possible to install it anymore in Python 3.10 on Windows

Answer (score 3):

You can use PyBluez:

```
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

Comment: Can you post example of the output it gives?